# Linear equation System

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the solutions of the following system:

$  14x_1 + 35x_2 -  7x_3 -  63x_4 = 0 $

$ -10x_1 - 25x_2 +  5x_3 +  45x_4 = 0 $

$ 26x_1 + 65x_2 - 13x_3 - 117x_4 = 0 $

- 4 unknowns (n), 3 equations

$ Ax=0: $

$ \begin{pmatrix} 14 & 35 & -7 & -63 & 0 \\ -10 & -25 & 5 & 45 & 0 \\ 26 & 65 & -13 & -117& 0  \end{pmatrix} $

Is there really more than one solution because of:

- $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A') = 1 < n $

What irritates me:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LinearSolve%5B%7B%7B14%2C35%2C-7%2C-63%7D%2C%7B-10%2C-25%2C5%2C45%7D%2C%7B26%2C65%2C-13%2C-117%7D%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%5D

Row reduced form:

$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2.5 & -0.5 & -9.2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &    \end{pmatrix} $

How to find a solution set ?

Comment: The rank of $A$ is not 1.

Comment: Why do you think the rank of A is not 1 ? All columns of the matrix are linear dependent vectors - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rank+%7B%7B14%2C35%2C-7%2C-63%7D%2C%7B-10%2C-25%2C5%2C45%7D%2C%7B26%2C65%2C-13%2C-117%7D%7D

Comment: Forgive me, I'm sorry: wrong mental check on the rows. Anyway, solutions can be found reducing with row operations the full matrix.

Comment: already reduced the matrix but how to find the solution set ?

Comment: The answer below is very good. I only add an interpretation of the reduction process: as the rank of $A$ is 1, this "really" means that only 1 row is non-redundant. Hence, you can focus on the first equation only: $14x_1+35x_2-7x_3-63x_4=0$. Now express $x_4$ in terms of the other variables to get $x_4=\frac29x_1+\frac59x_2-\frac19x_3$. Keeping $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ free, you should get exactly the same solution ;-) [up to a possible typo in the coeff of $x_4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many real solutions. Since there are more unknowns than equations, this system is called underdetermined. Underdetermined systems can have either no solutions or infinitely many solutions. Trivially the zero vector solves the equation:$$Ax=0$$
This is sufficient to give that the system must have infinitely many solutions. To find these solutions, it suffices to find the row reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix for the system. As you have already noted, the augmented matrix is:

\begin{pmatrix} 14 & 35 & -7 & -63 & 0 \\ -10 & -25 & 5 & 45 & 0 \\ 26 & 65 & -13 & -117& 0  \end{pmatrix}

Row reducing this we obtain:
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{-9}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0  \end{pmatrix}

This corresponds to the equation $$x_1+\frac{5}{2}x_2-\frac{1}{2}x_3-\frac{9}{2}x_4=0$$

You can then express this solution set with
 $$x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \frac{2}{9}x_1 +\frac{5}{9}x_2 -\frac{9}{4}x_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

As you have already noted, the rank(A) = 1, giving you $n-1=3$ free parameters. That is, you can supply any real values for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$ will be given as above. The choice to let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be free parameters here is completely arbitrary. One could also freely choose $x_1,x_2,x_4$ and have $x_3$ be determined by solving for $x_3$ in the above equation.

The wikipedia article on underdetermined systems has some more details and explanation than what I've provided: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system

Row reduced echelon forms can be computed using Wolfram Alpha by entering "row reduce" following by the matrix. If you're interested, Gauss-Jordan elimination is a pretty good method for calculating reduced-row echelon forms by hand.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I was already so far but I do not understand the context of the free parameters (n-1=3) How to express a solution set ?

Comment: Hopefully the edits I made will seem more clear. The best thing to do is to express the solution set as a vector. It is also good practice to explicitly state which variable you have selected to represent the free variables, i.e. which variables can be chosen arbitrarily from any real number.

Comment: great, thank you !!!!